# Password verify using PDO returns nothing

Tags: php, pdo, authentication, password-protection

I'm trying to create a login page but when I try and log in I get a blank page returned, I get no errors either.  I want to return a success or failure message based on the outcome of the login script.  Where am I going wrong?

Login page:

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_USERNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
    } catch   (PDOException $e) {
        print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
        die();
    }
$username   = $_POST['username'];
$password   = $_POST['password'];

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = : username LIMIT 1";
$query = $dbh->prepare( $sql );
$query->execute( array( ':username'=>$username ) );
$results = $query->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ); 

foreach( $results as $row ){ 
     if(password_verify($_POST['password'], $password)){
        echo 'verified';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'not verified';
    }
    }
```

The page to create a user:

```
$username = $_POST["username"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
//sets type to '1' which is used for a user.
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("insert into users set username=?, email=?, password=?, type= '1'");
$stmt->execute([$username, $email, $hash]);


echo "<p>Thank you for registering!</p>";
```

Comment: had you been using exceptions after opening your connection, it would have shown you the error, being a typo/syntax error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a space between the colon and "username"

```
'username = : username'
             ^
```

There should not be any spaces and to read as `:username`

A few lines below you are using:

```
array( ':username'=>$username )
```

Comment: Ah now its working, the problem I have now is that it is returning password not verfied even if I use the right credentials.

Comment: `$password   = $_POST['password'];` and below `password_verify($_POST['password'], $password)`. You are not verifying the password you are getting. Instead, make it `password_verify($password, $row['password'])`

Comment: I see, thanks this is changed. I understand the logic, sadly it's still not verifying so there may be another issue.

Comment: Try this hasher I'm using for password creation and verification: [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/W3Mp02YQ). It's created according to the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php). Read through it and edit as you see fit.